# Why was Michael's mother so ruthless to him in Prison Break?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, prison-break

In *Prison Break*, why was Michael's mother so ruthless and why did she want to kill Michael?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Christina Scofield was not trying to kill Michael at all. But she wanted to access Scylla. In the process of getting clemency for everyone Michael and the team stole Scylla from The Company. Then it somehow landed in the hands of Christina Scofield before being stolen back by Michael. Christina then kidnaps Lincoln and shoots him.

Michael was very close to Lincoln during his childhood had gone through so much that he doesn't feel much emotion towards his mother who lied and went away when he was young.

Hence Michael first tries to kill Christina himself and then through Mahone. But she survives and then she tries to kill him but Sara gets her first.